# Rails Routing Composite Primary Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a model in which it consists of 3 integers as its primary key.

```
property :id, Integer, :key => true
property :id2, Integer, :key => true
property :id3, Integer, :key => true
```

I need to create a route in which when queried with `http://myserver.com/item/$id/$id2/$id3` it will return that partiular item in the database.

Comment: `match '/item/:id/:id2/:id3'` will create the `params[:id]`,  `params[:id2]` and `params[:id3]`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah I was just missing the `:controller` and `:action` specifications.